# Virtualmin server send/receive mail via another Virtualmin server?

Tags: smtp, ubuntu-18.04, mail-server, webmin, virtualmin

I have set up virtualmin (v6.12) on two separate servers (both Ubuntu 18.04) with the intention of separating the webserver from the mailserver.

Do I need to fiddle with the postfix/dovecot files or is there an inbuilt feature that tells a virtualmin webserver to send/receive all emails via an external virtualmin mailserver?

Some forums pointed out that this can be done via `Webmin -> Postfix -> SMTP Authentication And Encryption > Send outgoing mail via host` but I'm not sure what exactly should I add here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can send mail via another Virtualmin system by using SMTP using the following steps:

**SMTP server** (The server to send mail from):

- Go to `Webmin > Postfix configuration`.
- Go to `SMTP Server Options` and make changes to `Restrictions on recipient addresses` based on your mailserver configuration.
- Go to `SMTP Authentication & Encryption` and make changes to `SMTP security options`, `SMTP recipient restrictions`, etc based on your mailserver configuration.

**SMTP Client** (The server connecting to the SMTP server):

- Go to `Webmin > Postfix configuration`.
- Go to `SMTP Client Options` and make changes to `SASL security options` and `Use TLS for SMTP connections` based on your mailserver configuration.
- Go to `SMTP Authentication & Encryption` and add your SMTP server hostname (with port) in `Send outgoing mail via host`, choose the relevant option in `Use SASL SMTP authentication?` based on your mailserver configuration and finally add the login details in `SMTP login to outgoing mail host`.

**N.B.** Most of the options that you need to set in the above steps will depend on how you configured your mailserver (Postfix, SASL, etc) hence the `based on your mailserver configuration`.